# Can ffmpeg encode video from frames of different sizes?

Tags: c, images, video, ffmpeg

I have a toolchain that produces frames that are usually 1920x1080, but occasionally 1919x1080 or 1920x1079.  (Yes, this is a bug.  Please read on.)  When ffmpeg encodes a video from it, with a command like

```
ffmpeg -y -r 30 -i foo/%04d.png -vcodec h264 out.mp4
```

then it prints remarks like

```
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:1919x1080 fmt:rgb24 to size:1920x1080 fmt:rgb24
```

but those frames, rather than being resized and included in `out.mp4`, are omitted from `out.mp4`.

Can those frames be included?  I found no mention of nonconstant frame size on forums and in documentation, but ffmpeg itself here *claims* to resize the frame.  (The remark is printed at line 1688 of ffmpeg.c.  There, a flag `resample_changed` is set, which causes the width and height fields of `InputStream *ist` to be corrected.)

David Elliman may be reporting similar behavior in an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043841/ffmpeg-missing-image-frames-in-generated-video-from-images?rq=1 .

Comment: The best elaborated answer seems to be this one: http://superuser.com/questions/547296/resizing-videos-with-ffmpeg-avconv-to-fit-into-static-sized-player/547406#547406 which adds black borders to the videos of different frame sizes to avoid stretching (i.e. avoid changing the aspect ratio of the videos).

Comment: Pillar- or letter-boxing is appropriate when frame size changes a lot, but not in this case, when it changes by one or two pixels.  Then, flashing black borders would be distracting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the [`scale`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) video filter can provide what you're looking for:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -i foo/%04d.png -vf "scale=1920:1080,format=yuv420p" -codec:v libx264 out.mp4
```

This will force a size of 1920x1080 for each frame. This may result in a slightly stretched or squished image if your weird sized inputs are simply cropped instead of scaled incorrectly. If that is the case the consider using the [`pad`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) video filter instead but be aware that it will result in a solid colored bar to compensate for the missing pixels.

`scale` also accepts various [functions](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation) if you want to get fancy with it. See [Resizing videos with ffmpeg to fit into static sized player](https://superuser.com/a/547406/110524) for an example.

I added `format=yuv420p` because, with an RGB input for libx264, ffmpeg will attempt to avoid chroma subsampling resulting in YUV 4:4:4 planar pixel format which most players can not decode.

Answer (score 1):

Try omitting the `-r 30` parameter for the input framerate and use `-framerate 30` for the output framerate instead. I had the same problem and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to specify a scale mode for the resizing to work. I grabbed this from my implementation.

```
--custom-anamorphic --display-width 1920  --keep-display-aspect --modulus 8 --crop 0:0:0:0
```

Comment: Has this to do with ffmpeg? I don’t think so. Or tell me please how to use it with ffmpeg.

Comment: you can run any of these commands from the command line. any GUI you installed is a flavor of ffmpeg ( a wrapper around it).

Comment: Which version of ffmpeg do you think has these command line options? I couldn’t find a help file explaining the options you listed.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/550710/how-do-i-translate-handbrakecli-options-to-ffmpeg-options

Comment: Instead of just posting a link, you could have explained: Your answer uses *Handbrake* instead of `ffmpeg`. Has nothing to do with `ffmpeg`, except that this (*Handbrake*) is a tool which may also use `ffmpeg` as backend.